# Nested loop to print a number, with the same amount of astericks along side it

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user for a number (between 5 and 50 (inclusive)), then output to screen a countdown of the numbers starting with the given number and include on the same line the same number of asterisks.

E.g. 5 ***** 4 **** 3 *** etc….

I know I need a scanner and a nested for loop, but I'm unsure to which way to use these together, any tips?

```
//outer loop
for (int outer = 50; outer <= 5; outer--) {
            //inner loop
            for (int inner = 1; inner <= outer; inner++) {
```

I've no idea how to start using the scanner in this situation!

Comment: what did u try so far ? post the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "I've no idea how to start using the scanner in this situation"... well, you'd use the scanner to get the input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = scanner.nextInt();
        for(int i = count; i > 0; i-- ){
            System.out.print(i);
            for(int j=i; j>0; j-- ){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```